# Run dnscrypt-proxy automatically at startup on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dnscrypt-proxy

I added a command using startup Applications but it always fail.

```
/usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy -d -R opendns -a 127.0.0.2
```

In order to have it working properly I need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo dnscrypt-proxy -d -R opendns -a 127.0.0.2
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Seems like you did not add a sudo to gain root privileges to your startup command. Add it and make sure you also add the permission to run that specific command with sudo without being asked for a password. Therefore an additional config file has to be included in /etc/sudoers.d/ to set up this.

Comment: You should consider formatting Terminal commands and output as code.

Comment: I've finally be able to run it at startup by using visudo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should use the Ubuntu packages from my PPA as I usually provide the latest available version :

https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt

Explanations on how to use it are within a webupd8 article :

[Encrypt DNS Traffic In Ubuntu With DNSCrypt [Ubuntu PPA]](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html)